# Insert text mid-line with sed/awk

Tags: bash, sed, awk, grep

I want to insert a character between two numbers: `foo bar 12 34` to become `foo bar 12/34`.

So I want something like `sed` to match a space found between two numbers and substitute that with a slash, but I'm not sure how to do it.

I have `sed -e 's/[1-9][0-9] [1-9][0-9]/\//'` so far, but I know that substitues both numbers *and* the space with the slash. I need to find the space in the line that's between two numbers, but only substitute the space. Maybe I need `grep` to find it, but I still need the entire line to print in the end.

Any ideas?

Comment: @DevZer0 - Thanks guys! They all work perfectly, I don't even know which one to use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Trivial with `awk`:

```
echo 'foo bar 12 34' | awk '{print $1,$2,$3"/"$4}'
```

Identify the columns you want to separate with delimiters and put the delimiter in between.

If you have varied number of fields on a line, then identify the field you want to join with the next one using a loop.

Comment: I think I'll use this one, it looks the simplest to me. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. `awk` is much too powerful and this is the most basic implementation of it. If you do need assistance with varied data, come back with a new question and we shall make it work for you. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
sed 's|\([0-9]\) \([1-9]\)|\1\/\2|'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, i have tested out the following regexp.

```
echo "foo bar 12 23" | sed -e 's/\(.*\)\([1-9][0-9]\)\(.\)\([1-9][0-9]\)/\1\2\/\4/'
```